# Disallowing adblock.php in robots.txt causes Google to report "Severe health issues are found in your property"?

Tags: google-search-console, php, adblock

I need google don't crawl my adblock.php URL, after i added this URL in my robot.txt file like,

> Disallow: /adblock.php

The google shows report like,

[image]

I had added adblock.php to robots.txt because Google was indexing it instead of the home page URL.

Comment: You have to have it linked somewhere or possibly included in a sitemap. Do not do this. I do not know what the adblock.php file is exactly. Google is seeing your adblock.php file as a valid page which should not be the case unless it is one. Cheers!!

Comment: If you go to your site without a file name, such as example.com, do you see your home page?

Comment: What content is available at adblock.php?   Is it duplicate of the home page?   What is the purpose of that script?

Comment: Please edit this question to add the requested details.